# Jaxb2Marshaller xsd schema validation query

Tags: spring, jaxb

I am using spring 3.0.6 Jaxb2Marshaller using below configuration,

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPaths">
        <list>              
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.schema.external_request.event</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.schema.zzz.external_request</value>                      
        </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

I want to validate xml against against the external_request.xsd which it is not doing. Do I need to explicitly pass the **schema** property even if the generated sources have the annotation which mentions that element is required something like `@XmlElement(name = "abc", required = true)`. Has any one already faced this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hey may be instead of adding classes to `context paths` you can try adding it to `classesToBeBound` proprty

```
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.schema.external_request.event</value> 
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.schema.zzz.external_request</value>          
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please rate the answer if it helps.
cheers

Comment: But if I add classesToBeBound, I believe I will have to list all the classes in my case, they will be many. Also if new element gets added in xsd, I will have to update it frequently so I guess it will be difficult to maintain. I can give a try. Thanks for reply.

Comment: The issue i get from your post  is that @XmlElement(name = "abc", required = true) is not picked up by spring , hence i wanted you to try  classesToBeBound